# show suggestion from database in textbox click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to show suggestion on text text when user start inputting text in text box.
This is my text box.

```
 <div class="form">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="name"  
        CssClass ="input-text" ID="txtschoolCode" ></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
```

Here is my ajax function.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=txtschoolCode.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ChangeRequestForm.aspx/GetData",
                data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is my Code behind function.

```
         public static List<object> GetData(string pre)
    {
          List<object> obj = new List<object>();

           ActivityLogDAL getAutoData = new ActivityLogDAL();
           DataTable empResult = getAutoData.getAutoLoadData();
         // getting data in empResult
           foreach (DataRow dr in empResult.Rows)
           {

               obj.Add(dr);
           }
       // have values in obj
           return obj;

    }
```

It is giving me Alert("Error")  ;
what is wrong with the code

Comment: firstly you should learn how to debug ajax request so you can get the real error. Look in your console and network tabs in the browser tools. Get the actual HTTP code and response from the server to tell you the error. This info is also available to you in your JS as part of the XMLHttpRequest object in the error callback. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ in the section called "The jqXHR Object" to see what properties it exposes.

Comment: Then you can alert or log those to your console to give you more information. e.g. `console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status, XMLHttpRequest.statusText, XMLHttpRequest.status, XMLHttpRequest.responseText);` might be a useful set of data. If the server simply returns a "500 internal server error", then the real error underlying _that_ error message should hopefully be logged server-side in the Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: Also a bit of advice, don't build your data string by hand, it's too error-prone. `data: JSON.stringify({ "pre": request.term })` is a better way. There's actually a chance this could be related to your issue, depending what error you're getting from the server.